# Why is this android style not smooth during multitask?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-manifest, android-styles

Check out this style for an android app

```
<style name="TestTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.NoActionBar.TranslucentDecor">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>
```

Create a very basic android app, add this style to the styles.xml and set it in the manifest file. When you then start the app, and switch back and forth using the multitask button, you will notice that it is a bit laggy.

Why is that the case? Is there any way to improve this theme?

Comment: What's your testing environment?

Comment: I am testing this on a Nexus 4